# Entity has already been configured as non owned

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to configure an aggregate and its children but keep getting the error

`The entity type 'Rule' cannot be configured as non-owned because it has already been configured as a owned`

This is a snippet of my configuration for the child inside the parent configuration:

```
builder.OwnsMany(f => f.Rules, c =>
            {
                c.HasKey(f => f.RuleId);
                c.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(f => f.ParentId);

            }).Navigation(g => g.Rules);
```

My aggregate root

```
public class Parent : Entity, IAggregateRoot {
   public int ParentId {get; private init;}
   private readonly List<Rule> _Rules = new();
   public IReadOnlyCollection<Rule> Rules => _Rules;

   private Parent() { }
}
```

My rule entity

```
public class Rule : Entity {
    public int RuleId { get; private init; }
    public int ParentId { get; private init; }
    
    private Rule() { }

}
```

Any ideas? According to documentation I've done the configuration correctly

Comment: Check that you don't have any configuration set up to try and configure Rule elsewhere. That error looks like there is an outdated configuration somewhere getting called to set up Rule as a non-owned entity. Also ensure that your DbContext doesn't have a DbSet of Rule.

Comment: No other configuration relating to these entities anywhere or db  set rules. What ended up working was the normal seperate entity configuration mapping for my Rule class, has one with many etc (but obviously now I dont have the owned mapping).

Hoping someone comes along with an idea

Comment: Just noticed that Rules is a read-only collection. Try it just as a `ICollection<Rule>` without the _Rules and see if that mapping is happier. You may need to use something like a protected collection with a getter/setter, then a `[NotMapped]` public getter. (Not sure if field mapping is an option for Owned)